# Can UIStackView support iOS 8 or 7?

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8, autolayout, uistackview

I know that `UIStackview` is a new feature in iOS 9. If I want my app to support iOS 8 or iOS 7, does that mean I shouldn't use stack views?

Comment: no, documentation says its available in iOS 9 and later

Comment: For **June 2016** onwards, there's no reason to worry about anything below iOS9 ... https://developer.apple.com/support/app-store/

Comment: @JoeBlow you mean?

Comment: Android is good in this case atleast. Provide support library for the newly released controls!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It looks like it's for iOS 9+.

[UIStackView](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStackView_Class_Reference/)

> #### Availability
>
> Available in iOS 9.0 and later

Answer (score 16):

[`UIStackView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStackView_Class_Reference/) is only available in "iOS 9.0 and later".

If you need to support earlier versions of iOS, check out [`OAStackView`](https://github.com/oarrabi/OAStackView), a drop-in replacement which "implements most of the features from `UIStackView`" and supports iOS 7+.

A few minor features haven't been finished yet. I tried it out using the [UIStackView-Playground project](https://github.com/jstart/UIStackView-Playground) and it works pretty well.

Comment: nice API! If I set one of the subviews hidden, would OAStackView adjust the constraints automatically?

Comment: hi @Yon, since when?

Comment: @Ted Recently I am using OAStackView in my project. I have tested this feature by myself.

Comment: Does OAStackView automatically set constraints like the UIStackView? It doesn't seem to be doing it for mine.

Answer (score 2):

You could also check out MarkupKit (I'm the project's author):

https://github.com/gk-brown/MarkupKit

The `LMColumnView` and `LMRowView` classes are very similar to `UIStackView` but work with iOS 8. They also have a couple features that `UIStackView` doesn't have, such as the ability to set a background color and weight-based distribution.

See this article for more information:

https://gkbrown.wordpress.com/2015/09/29/using-uistackview-with-markupkit/

Answer (score -1):

UIStackView is supported only in iOS 9+. **For people looking for a backport to iOS7/8:**

https://github.com/oarrabi/OAStackView